# Selecting Polyline between two point features (multiple start and end points)

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have a set of highways and want to see all the closures on them in a year.

Line feature: Highway shapefile

Point feature: Start and end coordinates of all the closures

I connected the start and end coordinates with a Euclidean line, then created a buffer around the line and finally intersected the buffer with highway but it selects many unwanted segments. A sample of highway and points is attached.

[image]

Comment: You should explore the help file on using a network dataset to generate the lines along highways between the pairs of points.

Comment: Thank you. I saw one your old answer ( https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/315845/selecting-polyline-between-two-point-features-using-modelbuilder/433805#433805) and explored some linear referencing too. I am relatively new to arc, if you can please share a link of the help files or a Youtube video that would be great. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Find Route, which doesn't work on any base network but ended up giving me as answer anyway